# Is there a way to disable Okami's motion blur on PC without using a mod?

Tags: okami, okami-hd

I just started playing Okami HD on the PC (from Steam), and it's wonderful. But it doesn't appear to have any in-game option to turn off the motion blur. (This doesn't bother me during the actual game, but it does in screenshots.)

I know there are a couple of mods that can do this. But is there any way to do it *without* installing a mod?

I did find a configuration file that looks promising: ~/AppData/Roaming/OKAMI HD/okami_cnf.ini.

```
[SystemInitialize]
Vsync=1
AFMode=4
TQMode=0
PPAAMode=0
RenderScale=10000
WindowSize=8
WindowType=2
RefleshRate=0
AAMode=3
WindowX=100
WindowY=100
```

Perhaps one of these options is the key?

Comment: AF = Anisotropic Filtering, AA = Anti-Aliasing. PPAA sounds like a form of anti-aliasing (post-processing?) as well. 'Refleshrate' is hilarious. I can't directly place TQMode, however, although it could be Texture Quality.  You could try changing that option?

Comment: Dunno if this is of any help - https://steamcommunity.com/app/587620/discussions/0/1617220671493969747/

Comment: What's DSR? Does that mean I can take even higher resolution screenshots? That would be fantastic!

Comment: @Joachim Hm, neither TQMode nor PPAAMode seem to be changing anything.

Comment: Why are you opposed to using a mod?